# How to show image for 30 seconds then show another one after 30 seconds for multiple images?

Tags: java, android-studio

I only managed to change between 2 images but I would like to change more than 2 images. I am creating a fitness application where each exercise is 30 seconds long, after 30 seconds, the next exercise starts. Each workout has about 5 exercises but I am only able to change between 2 images. Currently, after the timer hits 30 seconds, it will change to the next image but the timer stops there. I heard that I need to use array and loop but I am not sure how to... Can somebody help me? Your help will be greatly appreciated as my submission is due in 5 days ><

```
private void startTimer(){
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDowntText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            exercise_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lunges);
            exercise_name.setText("Alternate Lunges");
        }
    }.start();
    mTimerRunning = true;
}

private void updateCountDowntText(){
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 30;

    String timeLeft = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", seconds);
    timerValue.setText(timeLeft);
}
```

Comment: Make an exercise class. Then create a list of all the exercises and iterate through it.

Comment: erm i'm not very sure how to which is why I asked ><

Comment: Creating the list and iterating through it. currently after 30 seconds it will change to another picture but the timer stops there it does not count down from 30 seconds

Comment: So if you have an exercise class I'm assuming it has the instance variables exercise name and image? So inside a for loop. Just set the exercise name and image and countdown the timer for each exercise in your exercise list.

Answer (score 0):

if your images are in R.drawables. then simply store the int reference in your array and then load that such as below,

```
  private int[] yourarray = {
R.drawable.star_00, //star_00 is image name here
R.drawable.star_01,
R.drawable.star_02,

};
```

Then when you want to load an image and draw to your imageview you do something like this from your Activity.

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(yourarray[n]);
```

Then call the setImageDrawable on ImageView. So:

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```